# Zend: Errors encountered while getting ContentSwitch helper

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm working my way through "Zend Framework: A beginners guide" by Vikram Vaswani, and currently I am attempting to get the ContentSwitch action helper for serving up XML content, however I encounter the following error message:

`Action Helper by name ContentSwitch not found`

When trying the following in my `init()` function:

`$contentSwitch = $this->_helper->getHelper('contentSwitch');`

All the sources say that this should work... however, it does not. I am using Zend Framework 1.11.11. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `contentSwitch` helper. It's `contextSwitch`: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch

Comment: Haha, ever felt like a complete idiot? That was me right then. Gracias for the feedback.